# Neo4j Cypher - Excluding relationships by type in cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Single relationships can be excluded by types using

```
Match (n:Person)-[r]-(m:Person) where type(r)<>"FRIENDS" return n,r,m
```

Is there a way to exclude multilevel relationships with cypher?

```
Match (n:Person)-[r*2..4]-(h:Hobby) where type(r)<>"FRIENDS" return n,r,h
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure, you can do that.   Like this:

```
Match (n:Person)-[r*2..4]-(h:Hobby) 
where NONE( rel in r WHERE type(rel)="FRIENDS") 
return n,r,h
```

Your query doesn't work because with multi-level paths, your `r` is a collection of relationships rather than a single one.  So you can use any of [the predicates on collections](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-predicates.html) to do the filtering that you want.

Here, I chose `NONE` with type(rel)=FRIENDS, which means that you'll only get the result back if NONE of the relationships are of type FRIENDS.   But you might instead want to use ANY or ALL, depending on what your query is supposed to mean.

Anyway, the main point here is to use a predicate function to turn a collection of things into a single boolean value.

Comment: ah, you were 10secs faster than me :-)

Comment: Interesting to see the two different formulations though, of course there are many equivalent ways of accomplishing the same thing!

Comment: that doesn't work if you have 1 or more. it seems to need to be 2 or more so the `r` is a list. How would you do for a 1 or more type relationship chain?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `ALL` or `ANY` predicates for this:

```
MATCH p=(n:Person)-[*2..4]-(h:Hobby) 
WHERE ALL(x in relationships(p) WHERE type(x) <> "FRIENDS")
RETURN n,r,h
```

Use the `ALL` predicate to make sure every relationship along that path is not a `FRIEND`. Use `ANY` to make sure you have at least one relationship not being `FRIEND`.